# How to override record-edit-form lightning-input-field custom CSS

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

We are using lightning record edit form in which there is lightning-input-field. this field is type of datetime. Please see screenshot attached. Start Date/Time and End Date/Time legend displaying in Bold and others are in normal font-weight. we want to remove it and tried many CSS but could not able to fix it Can anyone please help in fixing this issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you check if there are any custom field labels added to your component?

Comment: @rahulgawale, no it is just regular lightning-input-field elements under record-edit form. Not sure why only start date and end date is getting bold labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do.

Change the `variant` of the `lightning-input-field` to the `label-hidden` so it hides the standard label, now you can put the custom label using the below code.

```
<span class="slds-form-element_stacked">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="unique-id-of-input">Put your label here</label>
    <lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden"....>
    </lightning-input-field
</span>
```

Comment: its working, just have to add few css to make it proper align to input control. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HarshadKumbhar You may mark the answer as accepted if it is working for you.